# Java the best way of waiting & getting data from your client

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, networking

I started learning networking with the main networking package in JDK, it's pretty simple and easy after a few examples. But now I am interested into making multi-client applications like a chat system.

My structure idea so far is like this:

Connection handler class, which handles incoming connections, and holds the list of clients.
If new connection was found, create a new client object, start it's thread (Client object will implement runnable, so it will start it's own looping service, it will loop for new packets received), and add it to the list.

I create a new thread for each client instead of looping through all clients because the reading from client process stops the whole execution and will wait for the client to send data, which is kinda annoys me and this is my issue there.

I have created a simple console app that receives messages from the client, but now I want to detect disconnections. I read that bufferedReader .read() method returns -1 if user is not connected, so I thought I could loop and do that every number of seconds to every client, but the thing is, the client must send a packet in order to .read() it, so let's say if you do .read() it will wait & stop the whole thread until packet is received, (I think).

This is my current code which gets messages from client:

```
public boolean isConnected() {
    try {
        this.in.read();
        this.lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        if (!inConnection()) {
            System.out.println("User disconnected");
            try {
                this.destruct();
            } catch (IOException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

private boolean inConnection() {
    return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCheck < this.maxTime;
}

public void startClientService() throws IOException {
    while(!this.session.isClosed()) {
        if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.checkTime > 600) {
            System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - this.checkTime);
            if (this.isConnected()) {
                int packetType = this.dataIn.readInt();
                packets.getPacket(packetType);
            }
        }
    }
}

public void destruct() throws IOException {
    this.session.close();
    this.connection.removeClient(this);
    System.out.println("Session killed");
}
```

Basically what happens here, I am sending a integer packed from the client, I might have many things to do so therefore I can set many unique packet ID's, so if I want to receive and process a chat message, the packet id is 216, the client sends a int 216, server reads the packet, enters the switch loop of all packet ids and detects if its really 216, if yes it gets the instance of the packed class that handles messages & gets the bytes of the received message like this:

```
public class Chat implements Packet {

    @Override
    public void processPacket(Session c) {
        String message = readMessage(c);
        System.out.println("Message: " + message);
    }

    private String readMessage(Session c) {
        byte[] data = c.readBytes();
        String message = null;
        try {
            message = new String(data, "UTF-8");
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return message;
    }
}
```

And this is how I read bytes:

```
public byte[] readBytes() {
    int len;
    byte[] data = null;
    try {
        len = this.dataIn.readInt();
        data = new byte[len];
        if (len > 0) {
            this.dataIn.readFully(data);
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }       
    return data;
}
```

Okay my problem:

after adding the is disconnected detection, when I send my message, nothing happens. This is probably due to the .read() it stops and is waiting for a response. BUT if I write a message again, I will get the message in server.

This is my temporary, ugly client:

```
public class Client {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws UnknownHostException, IOException {
        Socket socket = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 43594);
        Scanner r = new Scanner(System.in);
        PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(socket.getOutputStream());
        String input;
        while(true) {
            input = r.next();
            if (input != null) {
                sendMessage(input, out);
            }
        }

    }

    public static void sendMessage(String message, PrintWriter out) {
        byte[] encoded = encode(message);
        out.write(0);
        out.println(encoded + "\n");
        out.flush();
    }

    public static byte[] encode(String s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(s);
    }

    public static String decode(byte[] s) {
        return DatatypeConverter.printBase64Binary(s);
    }   
}
```

My question is: What is a better way of reading data from client without making the application wait for it and actually loop everytime? OR maybe should I have a new thread for checking if user is online so it's 2 threads per 1 client?

If someone needs my session object (client object):

```
public class Session extends Thread implements Runnable {

    private Socket session;
    private Client client;
    private PrintWriter out;
    private BufferedReader in;  
    private PacketHandler packets;
    private DataInputStream dataIn;
    private ConnectionHandler connection;

    private final int checkTime = 1600;
    private final int maxTime = 22000;
    private long lastCheck;

    public Session(Socket session) {
        this.session = session;
        this.client = new Client(this);
        try {
            this.setStream();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        this.packets = new PacketHandler(this);
        System.out.println("[New session created]: " + session.getRemoteSocketAddress());
    }   

    public void setConnectionHandler(ConnectionHandler c) {
        this.connection = c;
    }

    public void run() {
        try {
            this.startClientService();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void setStream() throws IOException {
        this.out = new PrintWriter(this.session.getOutputStream());
        this.in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(this.session.getInputStream()));
        this.dataIn = new DataInputStream(this.session.getInputStream());
    }

    public Client getClient() {
        return this.client;
    }

    public byte[] readBytes() {
        int len;
        byte[] data = null;
        try {
            len = this.dataIn.readInt();
            data = new byte[len];
            if (len > 0) {
                this.dataIn.readFully(data);
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return data;
    }

    public String readMessage() {
        try {
            return this.in.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public boolean isConnected() {
        try {
            this.in.read();
            this.lastCheck = System.currentTimeMillis();
            return true;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            if (!inConnection()) {
                System.out.println("User disconnected");
                try {
                    this.destruct();
                } catch (IOException e1) {
                    e1.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }

    private boolean inConnection() {
        return System.currentTimeMillis() - lastCheck < this.maxTime;
    }

    public void startClientService() throws IOException {
        while(!this.session.isClosed()) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - this.checkTime > 600) {
                System.out.println(System.currentTimeMillis() - this.checkTime);
                if (this.isConnected()) {
                    int packetType = this.dataIn.readInt();
                    packets.getPacket(packetType);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public void destruct() throws IOException {
        this.session.close();
        this.connection.removeClient(this);
        System.out.println("Session killed");
    }

}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you writing this project as a learning exercise or to solve a problem?

Comment: @chrylis Learning, but can't really solve this problem tbh

Answer (score 1):

While I don't have time to look over all the code, here are two things that could help you out.

1) Use a defined message header.  Define X number of bytes of each message that the client will send to the server.  Use these bytes to define how long the message will be, and what type of message it is.  The server knows the length and layout of this header, and uses it to process the message in a particular way.  Example could be a header of one byte.  A value of 1 could be a I'm connected message.  2 could be I'm about to disconnect.  3 could be I'm currently away, and 4 could be an incoming chat message.

2)  There are 2 ways you can handle the input.  First is to use blocking IO, and create a separate thread to receive messages from each client. I believe this is what you are currently doing.  The second is to use non-blocking IO, and have a separate thread iterate over the open sockets and do a read.  Non-blocking will check if there is data to read, but if there is not, the thread will continue executing.

Comment: "Non-blocking will check if there is data to read, but if there is not, the thread will continue executing." How can I do this?

Comment: There are lots of tutorials out there on this. Just Google for "non-blocking IO Java" or something along those lines.